# jquery animating accordion header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate my accordion headers to simulate a ribbon dragged on to the wrapper on hover, and on hover out its dragged out of the wrapper.

Now if you check this first [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyFCw/37/embedded/result/) everything works fine, but when I try to animate the width of the h2 the ribbon bit outside of the wrapper disappears for a second and returns when the width animation is done. Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyFCw/40/embedded/result/) to see the problem.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a way to animate both the h2 and the span at the exact same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 gets an 'overflow:hidden' while animating, that's why your ribbon disappears. It seems that jQuery does this automagically, when animating a width.

What you could do is to use a different animation library like [emile](https://github.com/madrobby/emile), or to animate an emtpy property set and use the step callback of [$.fn.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to set the width.

Or you can modify your css that an overflow hidden on the H2 does not affect you.

Comment: Ty, `.css("overflow","visible")` after the animate() solved it